# unable to play html5 video in Ipad, the play button comes up but it is not clickable.

Tags: jquery, ios, html, ipad, video

i am developing an application where in i am using video tag to fetch the video inside a carousel. and i have made it to play for the first time. but i am not able to play the video in ipad, the play button comes up and there is a line coming up on it. like i am not able to click the play button.
i am using the below code.

```
<div class="carousel-inner embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <img data-ng-src="{{carouselArray[0]}}"alt="abn1"/>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-repeat="clist in carouselList" class="item">
        <img data-ng-src="{{imagelist.url}}" alt="abn2"/>
    </div>
    <div id="videoDiv" data-ng-show="showVideo">
        <video id="businessVideo" controls="true" height="554px;" width="100%" src="{{videoUrl[0]}}" type="{{videoFileType}}" preload="auto"></video>
    </div>
```

here videoUrl contains the url of the video which i am getting from a service call.
when the video is loaded and when the carousel slides to video element for the first time i am making it to play. and later on it will play when manually clicked.

```
$('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
            var totalItems = $('.item').length;
            var videoIndex = totalItems-1;
            var active = $(event.target).find('.carousel-inner > .item.active');
            var next = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var to = next.index();

            if(to == (totalItems-1)){
                if(!(playedFirstTime) && (media.readyState === 4) )  {
                        media.play();  
                        playedFirstTime = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

the video is playing properly in other browsers. but in **IPAD** the play button will come come up but i am not able to play the video. the play button has a line on it, like it is disabled.

Comment: what filename/type are you using? also if you try and open the video directly in Safari does it work?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal  i am using MP4 video format, and the video is stored in a content management system. when i call a service i will get the url pointing to the location of the video, and in html i am adding the type of the video as type="video/mp4". when i open the page in desktop using safari, the video will play fine.